# Exhaust vents exiting outside next to each other

Tags: bathroom, kitchens, dryer, exterior, exhaust

Is there any code that requires exhaust vents specifically for bathroom, Kitchen hood, and clothes dryer to terminate ‘x’ distance apart? For instance, placing these three exhaust exits on the same exterior wall 2 inches apart.

Comment: I am not aware of any spacing requirement , I have had a bathroom and dryer vent exit in the same stud bay so they were probably that close on the outside wall. The only thing I advise it to keep the dryer vent away from a condenser unit of an AC / heat pump to keep the lint & heat away from the unit. But that is not a code requirement.

Comment: exit vents not being close to intake ones is common sense with or without code... But 2 exit vents together - can't see an issue unless they go through a structural member then there may be code.

Comment: Is the dryer gas or electric?

Comment: Dryer is gas, kitchen hood exhausts gas range and oven combination if that counts.